# Opening compressed file attachments from GMail using Total Commander

Tags: gmail, 9.0-pie

On a newly configured Android 9 tablet, I installed **Total Commander** which can open most of the known compressed file types (`zip`, `tgz`, etc). I want to open such a compressed attachment directly from the Gmail application without first saving it. However, when I tap to a `zip` attachment in a mail, only a list of other installed applications that can handle the `zip` file are shown, but not Total Commander. How can I add Total Commander to this list?

Answer (score 3):

The Total Commander app can only work with saved ZIP files. This is defined in it's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/zip" android:scheme="file"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

As you can see there is only an entry for the `file` scheme, but no for the `content` scheme.

On Android users can not modify which app can handle what file format. Hence without a change by the author of Total Commands you can't do change this behavior on an unrooted device.

Comment: @Robert Can this be changed on a rooted device? How?

Comment: @Sruly You should be to modify a system wide xml file to show Total Commander in the list of apps. However Total Commander defines for some file types the content scheme and for some not, hence I would assume that the content scheme is missing for ZIP files is not an accident but was done intentionally because TC does not support this way of processing ZIP files. Therefore I would assume that modifying the system to show TC as target will result in an crash of TC.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the developer of this software. They are going to make the necessary modifications in the coming releases. Currently, the first beta version fulfills my need with a limitation ("*only when Total Commander was already running in the background when I click on the downloaded file*"). This limitation will be addressed in "*beta 2*". I will update my answer when this is generally available.